# Verify COSE data (P-256)

Tags: node.js, sha, cbor

I'm trying to verify the COSE data in the EU covid passports.

Verification works using https://github.com/panzi/verify-ehc, but this uses python libraries and I want to do it in JS.  Verification relies upon this public certificate:

```
let pKey = {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "snip",
    "y": "snip",
    "key_ops": [
        "verify"
    ],
    "kid": "snip"
}
```

The data I want to verify is COSE/CBOR data (`result` below), looking like

```
Tagged {
  tag: 18,
  value: [
    <Buffer a2 01 26 04 ...>,
    {},
    <Buffer a4 01 62 42  ... 179 more bytes>,
    <Buffer 7e a4 63 4f  ... 14 more bytes>
  ],
  err: undefined
}
```

I tried using the following

```
const cbor = require("cbor");
const ECKey = require('ec-key');

const result = cbor.decode(coseMessage);
let [headers1, headers2, cbor_data, signature] = result.value;

const key = new ECKey(pKey)
const verified =
    key.createVerify('SHA256')
        .update(cbor_data)
        .verify("", signature);
```

createVerify is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ec-key#createverifyhash). I have decoded `headers1` further and that claims the algorithm is `ES256` (I do not know how that corresponds to `P-256`).

I always get `verified: false` and suspect this is either because:

- I am using the wrong crypto tool; and/or
- I am verifying the wrong data (such that the signature cannot match)

All pointers welcome

Comment: any progress in this? I decoded protected_header too, but I'm stuck with decoding signature. But I am using pure javascript, not node:   
```protected_headerArr = typedArrayToBuffer(protected_header);
protected_headerData = CBOR.decode(protected_headerArr);
let kid  = protected_headerData['4'];```

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'cose-js' to verify. Since the data is signed following the COSE specification, it should be verified following the same spec. The spec defines the transformation of the CBOR data you have that must be performed before calling the verify function.

That being said, most of the COSE libraries in JavaScript do not include the full set of possible key algorithms used by the DCC. To verify the DCC correctly, I had to extend the COSE-JS lib to support RSA-PSS. You can see the full code here: https://github.com/Path-Check/dcc-sdk.js

Comment: Thanks, I've since found that my pKey above needed to be pre-processed more to be useable, and then cose-js can handle it. I'm still trying to work out what cose-js does to verify the payload as I want to implement this eventually in another language

Comment: hi, I try to implement PS256(RSASSA-PSS w/ SHA-256) in C/C++ with openssl, can I get some information from you?